# In Minecraft how do I make a video with my secound account moving around by itself?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q862ls4hrNE) if you don't understand the question. How do I make my POV like that with my second Minecraft account?

Answer (score 3):

These kind of videos are almost always done by use of a simple Video Camera mod like:

http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/938825-164-camera-studio-v2164-standalone-modloader-forge-video-recorder/

There are a few decent ones out there, so download one or two and see what you think! You'll need 2 accounts and 2 computers to do this.